# Limitar cópia de movimento em eixos específicos

Tags: python, jogos, blender

Estou desenvolvendo um game em Blender e programando em Python.
Tive que desenvolver soluções para trabalhar com oculus rift. Onde o meu personagem segue o movimento da visão do usuário.

Estou usando a seguinte função para copiar o movimento da câmera para o personagem:

```
import bge

def main():
    scene = bge.logic.getCurrentScene()

    mov1 = scene.objects["Camera"]
    mov2 = scene.objects["Cube"]

    mov2.worldOrientation = mov1.worldOrientation
```

Como faço para limitar o movimento de cópia do mov2 apenas nos eixos X e Y eliminando o movimento do eixo Z? Pois meu personagem flutua na cena quando olho para cima.

FPS funcionando
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dzchFfIwtSQ

FPS com oculus rift 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CwLc7XxRkr8

Answer (score 0):

**Atualização**: 
Se a propriedade é uma sequência de três elementos, é só replicar os dois primeiros e forçar o terceiro para zero:

```
mov2.worldOrientation = [mov1.worldOrientation[0], mov1.worldOrientation[1], 0]
```

**Original**:

Faz (muito) tempo que não mecho no Blender - mas você já tentou em vez de :

```
mov2.worldOrientation = mov1.worldOrientation
```

Fazer:

```
mov2.worldOrientation.x = mov1.worldOrientation.x
mov2.worldOrientation.y = mov1.worldOrientation.y
```

?

Comment: Sim, tentei. Me parece que a sintaxe correta para a função seria: mov2.worldOrientation = [1.0, 1.0, 0.0] onde: mov2.worldOrientation = [x, y, z]